# Get full name of outlook account with applescript

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

How can I get the name of an outlook account in microsoft outlook using applescript 
I've tried 
         tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
            set name to name of (get account)
            --Creates HTML signature using html code
            make new signature with properties {name:"Official Signature", 
            content:html_content}
        end tell
but it errors out as Can't get name of account. The account is a class and name is a property

Comment: That's because you need a to identify the `account`.  Also, don't use `name` as the variable identifier—it's the name of a property in the _Outlook_ scripting syntax (you can hopefully see why `set name to name of...` would be confusing to a script).  Try running the line `tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to get the name of every account`, and see what that returns.

Comment: Yea we’ll ideally I’d like to run this to find the name of every account on computers deployed. The return of the script says error can’t get every account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might find this useful:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
   set theAccount to the full name of the first exchange account
   --adapted from above comment account says it is an integer
   get the full name of every exchange account
end tell
```